# Minecraft Pi on Raspbian Buster

Tags: minecraft, pi-b

I have a Raspberry Pi B which is running Raspbian Buster (installed through NOOBS). I am trying to run Minecraft on it. I have downloaded the [Pi version of Minecraft](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/edition/pi/) from the Minecraft website, unzipped it and am running `./minecraft-pi` in the `mcpi` directory. I am getting the following error

```
./minecraft-pi: error while loading shared libraries: libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

I have done a bit of Googling and have tried

- `sudo apt-get install libgles2`
- Uninstalling, cleaning, and reinstalling `python-pygame`
- Running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib ./minecraft-pi` (I have looked in the `/opt/vc/lib` directory and can see `libGLESv2_static.a` but no `libGLESv2.so`)
- Navigating to the `minecraft-pi` file in the GUI desktop and choosing `execute` from the menu

None of the above have worked and I'm now stumped. My LINUX knowledge is still in its infancy so please keep answers simple or with an explanation.

Comment: The Pi version should be installable from 'Preferences','Recommended Software'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y minecraft-pi
```

Or install via the main menu (Preferences -> Recommended Software -> Games) as @CoderMike mentioned.

Downloading `minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz` directly provided most of what's needed but it doesn't include all dependencies, which APT takes care of.

Comment: Trying to install via terminal gives me `Unable to locate package minecraft-pi`. Using Buster released 2020-02-12

Comment: That could mean your package definitions are out of date. I have edited my answer to include `sudo apt update`. Multiple sources report minecraft-pi is still available in the Raspbian repositories.

Comment: On the May 23, 2023 version of Buster, after `sudo apt update`, the install attempt still reports "unable to locate."  It's also not in "recommended software."

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Minecraft (java) that can be played on 32bit Raspbian Buster is 1.12.2

Here is my tutorial:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=243946